# Using @JsonUnwrapped on nested objects

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

**Updated**

I'm trying to validate a Spring request.

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> performOperation(@Valid @RequestBody MyModel model) {
```

Here is my validator class:

```
class MyModel{
   @JsonUnwrapped
   Parent parent;
}

class Parent {
  Child child;
}

class Child {
   String field1;
   String field2;
```

In my actual use case, Parent has two different object children

I want the user to be able to pass in Json like this:

```
{
    Child: { 
      field1: 
      field2:
     }
}
```

and not like this:

```
{
   Parent: {
       Child: { 
         field1: 
         field2:
       }
    }
}
```

When I use @JsonUnwrapped, the user can only pass in data like this

```
{
   field1:
   field2:
}
```

But the values are not actually getting put into the Child object.

When I use @JsonUnwrapped to serialize a Java class to Json, I see that it seems to apply @JsoUnwrapped recursively, so that MyModel serializes to

```
{
   field1:
   field2:
}
```

I can't find any other options for @JsonUnwrapped to cause to to work only on one level

Comment: Not sure people follow your question... Are you asking how to map or how to validate? How jaxb is related here?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  It's not Jaxb, but Jackson.  I'm trying to Validate, so the user enters Json and Spring/Jackson converts to Java object.  But I want the Java object to have an additional wrapper

Comment: I re-worded the question so hopefully it is a little clearer

Answer (score 0):

Jackson version: **2.13.3**

The demo is shown below:

MyModel.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyModel {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Parent parent;
}
```

Parent.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyModel {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Parent parent;
}
```

Child.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Child{
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

MyTest.java

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.setParent(new Parent(new Child("ning",22)));
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(model);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
        //{
        //  "child" : {
        //    "name" : "ning",
        //    "age" : 22
        //  }
        //}
    }
}
```