# Validatng enums in Spring validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, enums

I'm doing request parameter validation from a Spring controller.  I have an Enum validator, similar to https://funofprograming.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/java-enum-validator/, which works fine if the enum field is directly in the object I'm using for validation.  But it doesn't work if that object contains other objects.

For example, here is the request in the Controller

```
@PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> performOperation(@Valid @RequestBody MyModel model) {
```

Here is the model I'm using to validate the request params

```
@ApiModel
public class MyModel {
   @ApiModelProperty
   @EnumValueValidator(enumClass = EnumName.class)
   public String provider;

   MyObject obj;
}

public class MyObject {
   @EnumValueValidator(enumClass = SomeEnum.class)
   public String anotherEnum;
}
```

In the above example, `provider` is validated with no problem.  But `anotherEnum` is not.  Is there a way for a Spring model to do a deep validation into objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should annotate `MyObject obj` with `@Valid` annotation as well. Just keep in mind that null objects are not validated, so probably you should do both:

```java
@NotNull
@Valid
MyObject obj;
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you.  Would you mind if I asked you to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891935/using-jsonunwrapped-on-nested-objects?  I'm having a related issue with a nested validator, where I want to flatten the top level, but not the lower levels.